# can ros communicate between different versions via WIFI?

Tags: ros, arduino, include, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Can two different versions of ros1 communicate between two different distributions or do all computers have to be the same?

Example between melodic on Raspberry PI (arm) and Noetic on Ubuntu (intel).

ta!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364122/can-ros-communicate-between-different-versions-via-wifi?/) by [l33](https://answers.ros.org/users/60418/l33/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2020-10-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-10-26**:
Wifi doesn't change anything here. It's a plain "can two different ROS versions communicate" type of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll point to an [answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/104086/is-it-possible-to-connect-machines-with-different-ros-versions/?answer=104096#post-id-104096) left by @Dirk Thomas.

> As long as the specific messages have not been changed between the two ROS distributions (which is only rarely the case) it should be work fine...

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2020-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4